# How do I make this menu delay its effect for a second?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make this side menu a little more user friendly. If you hover from the bottom up you have no trouble navigating through it, but if you hover from one above down, when you try to hover over another parent, it makes it difficult for the user to switch to another parent. What I thought it would be good was to delay its effect so the user has some time to switch from one parent to another.

```
    <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style>
#nav
{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;   
    float:left;
    background:white;
}
#nav li 
{
    list-style:none; 
    background:#f8f8f8; width:209px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666; 
}
#nav li a
 {
    display:block; 
    padding:8px; 
    border-left:4px solid #a89172; 
    text-decoration:none;  color:#4b4b4b;     
    text-transform: uppercase;     
    font-family:serif; 
    font-size: 15px;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
        -moz-transition:background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
        -ms-transition:background 0.2s, color 0.2s; 
        -o-transition:background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
        transition:background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}
#nav li a:hover
{ 
    border-left: 4px solid #d5bb8d; 
    background: #f8f8f8;     
    text-transform: uppercase;     
    font-family:serif; 
    font-size: 15px;
     -webkit-transition-delay:0.1s;     
        -moz-transition-delay:0.1s; 
        -ms-transition-delay:0.1s;     
        -o-transition-delay:0.1s;     
        transition-delay:0.1s

}

#nav li ul 
{ 
     visibility: hidden;    
     display:none;
      opacity:0;
  transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}



#nav li:hover ul
{
    margin-left:-2pc;   
    visibility: visible;
    display:block;
    opacity:1;
}

#nav li:hover ul li 
{
    background:#a89172; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
    border-left: 4px solid #d5bb8d;

}
#nav li:hover ul li a 
{ 
    color:#ffffff;     
    text-transform: uppercase;     
    font-family:serif; 
    font-size: 13px;

}
#nav li:hover ul li a:hover 
{ 
    background:#d5bb8d; 
    border-left: 4px solid #d5bb8d; 
    color:ffffff;    
    text-transform: uppercase;     
    font-family:serif; font-size: 13px;
}



}
/*box-shadow: 2px 2p*/
</style>


<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Dressage_c_6.html">Dressage </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Dressage-Arenas_c_171.html">Dressage Arenas</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Dressage-Arena-Packages_c_172.html">Dressage Arena Packages</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Dressage-Flower-Boxes_c_14.html">Dressage Flower Boxes</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Dressage-Accessories_c_13.html">Dressage Accessories</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Silk-Flowers_c_15.html">Silk Flowers</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Cavaletti_c_9.html">Cavaletti</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Training-Obstacles_c_173.html">Training Obstacles</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/Arenas/underConstruction.html" target="_blank">Western Dressage</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/Arenas/dressageArenaLayouts.html" target="_blank">Dressage Assembly Instructions</a></li>





      </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/Horse-Arena-Footing.html" target="_blank">Horse Arena Footing</a>
 <ul>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/PremierHT-Footing.html" target="_blank">Premier HT</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/master-blend.html" target="_blank">Master Blend Footing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/ggtfooting.html" target="_blank">GGT Footing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/ProTex.html">ProTex Arena Footing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/athletex.html" target="_blank">Athletex Arena Footing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/prostride.html" target="_blank">ProStride Arena Footing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/hydrokeep.html" target="_blank">Hydro-keep Arena Footing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/Horse-Arena-Footing.html">Arena Maintenance Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/newConstruction.html" target="_blank">Horse Arena Construction</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/otto-products/otto-perforated.html" target="_blank">Otto Sport</a></li>




 </ul>
</li>


<li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jumps_c_170.html" target="_blank">Horse Jumps</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Standards_c_7.html">Horse Jumps Standards</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Fills_c_11.html">Horse Jumps Jump Fills</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Gates_c_8.html">Horse Jumps Gates</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Poles_c_21.html">Horse Jumps Poles</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Flower-Boxes_c_176.html">Horse Jumps Flower Boxes</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Jump-Cups_c_62.html">Jumps Cups</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Accessories_c_18.html">Horse Jump Accessories</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Sponsor-Theme-Jumps_c_87.html">Sponsor / Theme Jumps</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Courses_c_17.html">Horse Jumps Courses</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Jump-Assemblies_c_19.html">Horse Jumps Assemblies</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Cavaletti_c_177.html">Cavaletti</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Training-Obstacles_c_178.html">Training Obstacles</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Mini-Pony-Kids-Jumps_c_131.html">Kids Jumps</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://horsejumps.net/Category/Standards/Jump-Assembly-Instructions.html" target="_blank">Jump Assembly Instructios</a></li>







    </ul>
</li>




<li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Barn-Stable_c_10.html">Barn & Stable</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/TrunksStorage_c_74.html">Trunks/Storage</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Carts_c_72.html">Carts</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Mounting-Blocks_c_73.html">Mounting Blocks</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Racks-Hardware_c_75.html">Racks & Hardware</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Feeders-Waterers_c_150.html">Feeders & Waterers</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/EZ-Grip-Mat-Mover_c_162.html">Ez-Grip Mat Mover</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dressagearena.net/pages/stallmats.html" target="_blank">Ruber Stall Mats</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dressagearena.net/pages/hoofgrid.html" target="_blank">Hoof Grid</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dressagearena.net/pages/barnaccessoriestrailer.html" target="_blank">Barn & Trailer Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://dressagearena.net/pages/barn-and-stables.html">Barn & Stable Packages</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dressagearena.net/pages/fencing.html" target="_blank">Vinyl Fencing</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Yard-Decor_c_155.html">Yard Decor</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://premierequestrian.com/category/footing-products/PremierGroomer.html" target="_blank">Arena Maintenance Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dressagearena.net/pages/fly_control.html" target="_blank"> Fly Control</a></li>




    </ul>
  </li>


<li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Rider_c_152.html">Horse & Rider</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Wireless-Audio-Systems_c_98.html">ComTek Wireless System</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Riding-Apparel_c_161.html">Riding Apparel</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Training-Obstacles_c_185.html">Training Obstacles</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Training-Accessories_c_186.html">Training Accessories</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Toys_c_187.html">Horse Toys</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Horse-Tack_c_188.html">Horse Tack</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.dressagearena.net/pages/horse_care_nutrition.html" target="_blank">Care & Nutrition</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLxtS4Ltt9gzaNqvUFitFaBK22GmcvPMFT" target="_blank">ProTips Video Clips</a></li>



    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Books-DVDs-Gifts_c_16.html">
Books/DVD's/Gifts</a>

<ul>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Books_c_70.html">Books</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/DVDs_c_140.html">DVD's</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://store.premierequestrian.com/Gifts_c_154.html">Gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.kidjumps.net/" target="_blank">Kid Jumps</a></li>



    </ul>
</li>



</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.nav ul li').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true,false,true).slideToggle(400);
});

</script>
```

Comment: You have `<ul id="nav">` but the selector in jQuery is `$('.nav ul li')` that will never be applied. It should be `$('#nav ul li')`, unless there is some code missing above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `delay()`. See API here: [delay()](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)